# How to define Rb0 to Rb6 = hex (x%10); // no Rb7 pin

Tags: pic, mikroc

Using MikroC Pro for PIC16f73 to multiplexing 7 segment the written program is:

```
PORTB = Hex (x%10);
```

There `PORTB` means `RB0` to `RB7` total 8 pins are includes, but I want to use only 7 pins for 7 segments `RB0` to `RB6`, and the pin `RB7` as other O/P just 0 or 1.

As like `Rb0` to `Rb6 = hex (x%10)` and `Rb7_bit = 0 or 1`

so how to define the line `Rb0 to Rb6 = hex (x%10);`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
uint8_t   Pin_Value;

Pin_Value = Hex (x%10);
Pin_Value |= 0x80;       //set bit RB7
Pin_Value &= 0x7F;       //clear bit RB7
PORTB     = Pin_Value;
```